# Regex SerDe doesn't support the serialize() method error

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql, regexserde

I have a table structure as below.

```
CREATE TABLE db.TEST(
f1 string,
f2 string,
f3 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'input.regex'='(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})' )
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://nameservice1/location/TEST';
```

I tried to insert a record into the table as below.

```
insert overwrite table db.TEST2 
select '12' as a , '123' as b , '1234' as c ;
```

While trying to insert data into the table, facing the below error.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Regex SerDe
>   doesn't support the serialize() method
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe.serialize(RegexSerDe.java:289)

Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong SerDe class. [**org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe**](https://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/apache/hive/0.10.0/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html) does not support serialization. Look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) - **serialize** method does nothing but throws `UnsupportedOperationException` exception:

```
 public Writable serialize(Object obj, ObjectInspector objInspector)
      throws SerDeException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
          "Regex SerDe doesn't support the serialize() method");
}
```

**And the solution is**

to use another SerDe class:
[**org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe**](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.html), it can serialize the row object using a [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) string.  Serialize format should be specified in the `SERDEPROPERTIES`. Look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) for more details.

Example of SerDe properties:

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'input.regex' = '(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})','output.format.string' = '%1$2s%2$3s%3$4s')
```

For your table it will be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE db.TEST(
f1 string,
f2 string,
f3 string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'input.regex'='(.{2})(.{3})(.{4})',
  'output.format.string' = '%1$2s%2$3s%3$4s' )
LOCATION
  'hdfs://nameservice1/location/TEST';
```